# Issue on Adding Keyframe to animated div

Tags: css, css-animations

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/darLuges/) and let me know why the keyframe animation not working>

```
<div class="showbox"></div>

<style>
.showbox {
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    background:red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-transition:1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:1s ease-in-out;
    transition:1s ease-in-out -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1000ms;
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
        transform:scale(1);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
        transform:scale(1.2);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.3);
        transform:scale(1.3);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
        transform:scale(1.2);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
        transform:scale(1);
    }
}
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: typo mistake add `;` after this `transition:1s ease-in-out `

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/darLuges/1/

Comment: THanks Chipchoclate.py,

Comment: Thanks Virorino, it is working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest variant http://jsfiddle.net/darLuges/2/

```css
.showbox {
  height:15px;
  width:15px;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transform-origin:50% 50%;
  transform:scale(1);
  animation: pulse 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}
@keyframes pulse {
  to  {transform:scale(1.3);}
}
```

```html
<div class="showbox"></div>
```

(than add back the xBrowser -vendor- prefixes)

Comment: @Suffii that's not the code I've gave you. Also have you noticed you're missing an `;`??

Comment: @Suffii does this works? http://jsfiddle.net/darLuges/2/ If it works that's cause you did not read the last line of my answer.